# Why does 'printf "%A" None' output null

Tags: f#, option-type

Why does `printf` output `Some x` for `Some x`, but `<null>` for `None`?

```
> printfn "%A" (Some 123);;
Some 123
val it : unit = ()

> printfn "%A" None;;
<null>
val it : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 5):

In compiled code, F# uses the `null` value to represent the `None` case of `option<'T>` for efficiency. You can actually use the same for your own discriminated unions by using the `CompilationRepresentationFlags.` `UseNullAsTrueValue` compilation flag (see [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.compilationrepresentationflags-enumeration-%5bfsharp%5d)).

You can see that this is what's going on by using the `Object.ReferenceEquals` method:

```
> let n = None;;
val n : 'a option

> System.Object.ReferenceEquals(n, null);;
val it : bool = true
```

Why does `printfn "%A"` just print the internal representation rather than recognizing that this actually represents the `None` case?

I think the answer is that printing is done dynamically using reflection and so the argument is just converted to a value of type `obj` at some point. Once you have a value `null` of type `obj`, it is not possible to recover what type it was before casting and so you cannot find out that `null` actually represents `None` (because `null.GetType()` fails). Presumably, the printing could use the static type information to get type information that way - but that would probably be more tricky to implement.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually older behavior that won't go away. Tomas' answer is correct for older FSI, but if you install something newer (like .NET Core 3.1 latest, or .NET 5 preview) you'll see with `dotnet fsi` that `None` formats as `None` with your example.

Comment: According to `dotnet --info` I'm running 3.1.201 but I still get the `<null>` behavior.

Comment: That's an older SDK. Looks like there isn't an update since March 24th outside of Visual Studio? Either way, this is changed now.

Comment: @PhillipCarter That's neat! Has the behaviour of `printfn "%A"` been changed so that it uses the static type information? Or is there some other magic involved??

Comment: The answer is, "it depends"! Unfortunately it's a little confusing when looking at the F# codebase, but the core file here uses reflection: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/utils/sformat.fs

But other formatting does use compiler internals: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/NicePrint.fs